# Cloud function trigger on document update

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to fire my cloud function if theres a document update on `users/{userId}`

I have a signIn method that's fired everytime a user logs in

```
signin: (email, password, setErrors) => {
    firebase
      .auth()
      .signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
      .then(() => {
        const isVerified = firebase.auth().currentUser.emailVerified
        const userUid = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid
        const db = firebase.firestore()
        if (isVerified) {
          db.collection('/users')
            .doc(userUid)
            .update({ isVerified: true })
        }
      })
      .catch(err => {
        setErrors(prev => [...prev, err.message])
      })
  },
```

Nothing fancy, aside from the basic log in stuff, it also checks if the user has verified their email, if it is verified it will update the collection for that user. Everything is working as intended here.

However I can't seem to get my cloud function to fire.

Basically, it's listening for changes on ther `user` collection. If `users/{userId}` document has `isVerified` and the user email address ends with `xxxx` it should grant them admin privledges.

```
exports.updateUser = functions.firestore.document('users/{userId}').onUpdate((change, context) => {
  const after = change.after.data()
  if (after.isVerified) {
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
      if (user.emailVerified && user.email.endsWith('@xxxx')) {
        const customClaims = {
          admin: true,
        }
        return admin
          .auth()
          .setCustomUserClaims(user.uid, customClaims)
          .then(() => {
            console.log('Cloud function fired')
            const metadataRef = admin.database().ref('metadata/' + user.uid)
            return metadataRef.set({ refreshTime: new Date().getTime() })
          })
          .catch(error => {
            console.log(error)
          })
      }
    })
  }
})
```

Right now the function is not firing, any ideas?

Comment: It could be firing, just not entering in that big if() {...}

How do you know it is not firing? Did you check your functions log and check if it is not firing?

Comment: Yeah I did, logss are empty

Comment: place a log before if (after.isVerified) {} and try again. 
Something like console.info(JSON.stringify(after))

Comment: Ok, it looks like it's firing but the code block (after.isVerified) is not executing...is it possible that I can't retrieve the user with firebase.auth()?

Comment: That is indeed the problem. I'll write up an answer.

Comment: What did print console.info(JSON.stringify(after)) ??

Comment: @CodigoMorsa It printed all the fiels on the `user/{userId}` collection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code in Cloud Functions runs as an administrative account, which cannot be retrieved with the regular Firebase Authentication SDK. In fact, you should only be using Firebase Admin SDKs in your Cloud Functions code, in which the `onAuthStateChanged` method doesn't exist.

It's not entirely clear what you want this code to do with the user, but if you want to check whether the user whose `uid` is in the path has a verified email address, you can [load that user by their UID](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#retrieve_user_data) with the Admin SDK.

To ensure that the `uid` in the path is the real UID of the user who performed the operation you can use security rules, as shown in the documentation on [securing user data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions#authentication).

Comment: I am trying to grant admin access to specific users, I don't really want this done client side so I've opted for the cloud functions. The above method executes once the user verifies their email address, if the address ends with `xxx` grant admin access - I'm not sure if this is the best way of doing it, but I just need a secure way to grant admin access, based on the currentUser.props

Comment: That's what I described in my answer: you can use the Admin SDK to look up the user's properties. I added an explanation on how to also use security rules to ensure the UID is correct.

Answer (score 1):

I support what Frank said.

You can fetch users with admin in this way:

```
if (after.isVerified) {
  admin.auth().getUser(userId)
    .then((userData) => { ...
```